# Как в Room сделать несколько методов insert с похожими параметрами

Tags: android, android-room

Нужно сделать в RoomDao два метода:

```
@Insert
void insert(List<Model1> list1);

@Insert
void insert(List<Model2> list2);
```

Но в таком случае он первый метод подсвечивает ошибкой, где написано:

```
both methods have same erasure
```

Как такое можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это следствие, т.н. стирания типов (подробнее [тут](https://blog.xapie.nz/2013/12/01/erasure/)). После компиляции `T` в generic-ах превращается в `object` (см. по ссылке выше) и получается, что у Вас 2 метода с полностью идентичной сигнатурой.

Исправить можно достаточно просто. Нужно создать отдельный `DAO`для каждой модели и не смешивать разные модели в одном `DAO`.